# Measure of variation(?) of multidimensional polynomial function

Tags: polynomials, covariance

I have a multidimensional function

$$\mathbf{f}(x) = [f_0(x), ... , f_N(x)]$$

where $f_n$ are real-valued trigonometric polynomials.

I want to measure how much $\mathbf{f}(x)$ varies over some range of $x$, but this should be invariant to the magnitude of $\mathbf{f}(x)$. For example if $\mathbf{f}(x) / \|\mathbf{f}(x)\|$ is the same for all $x$ the measurement should be 1, and if it varies it will be less than 1, approaching 0 with more and and more variation.

For example, one measure is

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left(\int_a^b f_n(x) dx\right)^2}}{\int_a^b \left(\sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{N} f_n(x)^2}\right) dx}$$

The problem is I want to do this algebraically, and for most trig. polynomials there is no expression for their square root.

What other measurement could I try?

The other requirement is that it is invariant to rotations. For example if

$$\|[f_0(x), ... , f_N(x)]\| = \|[\alpha_0 f_0(x), ... , \alpha_N f_N(x)]\|$$

for a set of scalars $\alpha$ the measurement should be the same for both.

Comment: If the only problem with the measure you wrote was in the square roots, you could just drop them -- but it seems that measure doesn't really do what you want, since e.g. it would vanish for a single component linearly changing from $-1$ to $1$.

Also, do you really mean "real-valued trigonometric polynomials in $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$", not "trigonometric polynomials in $x$" or "real-valued polynomials in $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$ with $x\in\mathbb R$"?

Comment: @joriki I dont think I can drop the square roots from the denominator - it is the two sides of the Cauchy inequality in a fraction if that helps. For the 1-D case (single component) yes you are right, let us consider diminsion 2 or above instead. I've updated the question re trigonometric polynomial.

Comment: i.e. given a bunch of vectors, the length of the sum of vectors <= the sum of the lengths of the vectors.

Comment: Sorry, you were right about the square roots.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like

$$
\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\frac{\left(\mathbf f(x)\cdot\mathbf f'(x)\right)^2}{\left(\vphantom{\mathbf f'}\mathbf f(x)\cdot\mathbf f(x)\right)\left(\mathbf f'(x)\cdot\mathbf f'(x)\right)}\mathrm dx\;?
$$

You probably won't like the denominator, but as no-one else has answered, it's at least another direction to think into.